# Shell script to find and resize images that have

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I'm trying to create a shell file I can set and forget...

Images with resolutions higher than 1920px resizes. Higher than 1920 seems to me too high for an e-commerce store anno 2018 ...
On an 8K+ image, an iPhone in Chrome bv simply crashes...

I have already replaced the scripts in as many places as possible so that front-end appropriate resolutions are shown and therefore no original files are simply resized. Ex 4000 x 6720 original, are now 500 x 1000's and are shown at 250 x 500 (so it is still sharp on retina).
These will then be in this lower resolution in the Magento Cache and then in Varnish Cache.

The idea is now to create a shell script that will clean up these "too large" files, resized themselves:

```
find /home/customer/customer.com \
  -type f \
  -regex "^. * \. \ (png \ | jpg \ | jpeg \) $" \
  -exec identify -format "% d,% w /% f,% h \ n "{} \; \
  | awk -F ',' '$ 2> 1080 && $ 3> 1920' \
  | grep "png \ | jpg \ | jpeg"
```

Gives me:

```
/home/sample/sample.com/media/catalog_fm/1453138191_LIU.JO_Dames_kleed_P16049T1633_nero_2_x15148601020101.jpg, 1440, 2160
/home/sample/sample.com/media/catalog_fm/1446052276_LIU.JO JEANS_Dames_vest_W65221E0139_22222_2_x14864501010101.jpg, 1440, 2160
/home/sample/sample.com/media/catalog_fm/1446655568_LIU-JO ACCESOIRES_Dames_shoes & boots_S65019P0055_22222_4_x14874601010101.jpg, 1440, 2160
...
```

The intention is to resize this now as follows:

```
convert FILENAME -verbose -resize x1920 FILENAME
```

I want to do all of these separate steps in a single shell file. Now I copy the generated file > .txt and extract it, run the script with the copy pasted data manually.

Comment: Howdy -- was reverting the whitespace intentional? Needing to scroll left-to-right to read the code is unfortunate.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy no not at all. If this helps resolve the question; be my guest and make it more readable.

Comment: He already did, and you undid the change ;)

Comment: BTW, is the spacing here identical to your real code, or were a bunch of changes added when trying to ask the question? (This looks like it's asking for filenames with spaces in them, which doesn't make much sense; similarly, `\n` doesn't work if you put a space before the `n`, and `png|jpg|jpeg` is very different from `png | jpg | jpeg`)

Comment: None of your sentences ever seem to end! Neither your title nor your question actually says what you want to do to which files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your approach is the best, you can tell convert to only resize images if they are larger, IIRC:

```
convert -resize ${MAXWIDTH}x${MAXHEIGHT}\>  ${FILENAME}
```

So you can just find all the pictures and unleash find on them:

```
find . -type f \( -name "*.png" -or -name "*.jpg" -or -name "*.jpeg"\) -exec convert -resize ${MAXWIDTH}x${MAXHEIGHT}\> {} \;
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed.